# Consider the isometry $ T: \mathbb{R} ^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the isometry  $ T: \mathbb{R} ^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $  represented by the matrix $ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & \sqrt 3/2 & -\sqrt 3/2 \\ \sqrt 3/2 & -1/2 & 3/2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $  , where $ T : \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end {pmatrix} $ . **Is the isometry Direct?  What kind of map is T ? ** $$ $$ I know that if after isometry  transformation of the vertex  A , B , C of a triangle remains same in orientation , then the Isometry is **called Direct isometry .** But now I can't  proceed . I calculated T to be translation . Is it right ?  please help me .

Comment: Its determinant is $-1$.

Comment: then what can i know from determinant ?

Comment: i think it is direct isometry

Comment: Your definition of a "direct isometry" seems appropriate for an isometry of the 2-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not for an isometry of the 3-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @LeeMosher This isn't an isometry of $\Bbb R^3$. I presumed the $\Bbb R^3$ in the title was a typo for $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You might be right, but the whole thing is ambiguous and the OP has to tell us what he means.